# Is there a preferred placement of termination resistor for a differential clock line?

Tags: pcb, clock, layout, termination, differential

Looking at a reference design board from Xilinx, we noticed the placement of the termination resistor for a differential clock line (~300 MHz):

[image]

The resistor is placed not at the closest possible location, which would be right under the vias which receive the clock (there appears to be a lot of space), rather, it is placed "far away", to the left of the vias. We are wondering if there is a good reason to place a differential termination resistor that way. Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of part is that that the clock is connected to? Is it a DIP logic IC? Or some kind of adapter to put the FPGA on a mezzanine card? Is the FPGA driving the clock and the DIP is receiving it or the other way around?

Comment: @ThePhoton: The clock is driven by an FPGA (with the red differential line that you see in the picture). The receiver is a BGA DDR part. The circled vias receive the clock, and the yellow differential line is routed to the termination resistor. My question was, why not place the termination resistor even closer to the receiving vias. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Termination resistors sit at one of two places:  As close to the driver as possible (for source termination), or as close to the end of the trace as possible (for the kind of termination that you have).

Notice that I said "as close to the end of the trace as possible", and not "as close to the receiver as possible"?  There is a difference!

Most people think of the signal chain for end termination being like this:  Driver --> Long Trace --> Termination --> Receiver.  But that is incorrect.  The termination should be at the end of the signal.  Like this:  Driver --> Long Trace --> Receiver --> Termination.

If you have several receivers, then you get this:  Driver --> trace --> receiver1 --> trace -> receiver2 --> termination.

The reason for this is that the termination prevents the signal from reflecting back to the receiver(s) and corrupting their signal.  In theory you could have a super long trace from the last receiver to the terminator and that would work just fine!

That is why your termination resistor is not near the driver-- because it doesn't have to be.  The resistor is at the end of the line, right where it should be.  There are other reasons why the resistor is placed that far away, but that isn't too important.

As for the little squiggles, that is because in a differental signal the lengths of the two traces should be identical in length.  The Squiggles are done to adjust the length of one trace to make it match the other trace.

Comment: Nice explanation of something I couldn't find quite the words to express so clearly.

Comment: @David Kessner: The circled vias in the picture are the receiver of the clock, not the source. So my question actually was, why not put the termination resistor even closer to the receiver, instead of getting a bit further away from the receiver?

Comment: @SomethingBetter  I understood your question, you didn't understand my answer.  Simply put, it is not important to have the termination closer to the receiver.  It is important to have the termination at the end of the line.

Comment: @DavidKessner: OK. From reading your initial answer I thought you seemed to think the encircled vias were the transmitters. So you're saying they could have placed the termination resistor right under the receiving vias, or even further away and it would be just the same. The only important thing is that we have a termination resistor at the end of the transmission line.

Answer (score 2):

Like embedded.kyle says, the squiggle is a clue, but I disagree about the meaning. It's absolutely certain that they need to design with controlled impedance for 300 MHz, squiggle or now squiggle.

What the squiggle says to me is that they are being very careful about matching the **trace length** between the two lines in the differential pair. The reason to do this is to minimize common-mode reflections on the line, which could conceivably cause an emi problem. I think they moved the terminating resistor to make room for the squiggle.

However, given the frequency (300 MHz) and the size of the squiggle, I believe they are over-designing this. That small a squiggle is unlikely to have any meaningful effect at that frequency.

That said, they don't cause any problems with this design.  What they've done is just move the termination down the line past the receiving part. This is a perfectly good design, and better than what you usually see, which is to put the termination first and then run a stub for a few more mm to reach the receiving part. In the case you show, the receiving part just causes a slight capacitive shunt at a midpoint on the line.

Answer (score 0):

The squiggle in the one trace is a clue. Since they put that squiggle in there, the designers are concerned with matching the impedance of the traces.

The following is from an [Altera App Note](http://www.altera.com/literature/an/an224.pdf):

> ### Differential Pair Termination
>
> Differential signal I/O standards require a termination resistor
> between the signals at the receiving device (see Figure 31). For the
> LVDS and LVPECL standard, the termination resistor should match the
> differential load impedance of the bus (i.e., typically 100Ω).

[image]

Xilinx has similar literature but I found the Altera note to be more concise.

So the reason the termination resistor is not as close as possible to the source is because the impedance of the traces matters when trying to adhere to the [Low-Voltage Differential Signaling (LVDS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-voltage_differential_signaling) or [Low-Voltage Positive Emitter-Coupled Logic (LVPECL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emitter-coupled_logic) standards.

---

## Edit:

Taking into account your comment and the other answers, the above does not make sense.

As the others have said, it is to match the trace length to reduce the effects of common-mode reflections that can occur when using single-resistor termination of a differential signal.

[image]

[Dr. Howard Johnson](http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/edn/DifferentialTermination.htm) explains it better than I ever could:

> Terrible things can happen to these common-mode artifacts if your
> trace delay equals one-quarter of the clock period. In that case, the
> little common-mode artifacts build and superimpose, cycle after cycle,
> magnifying your common-mode signal-input-range problems at the
> receiver and also magnifying the radiated emissions.

So, as David Kessner said, they have extended the trace length beyond the receiver and before the termination resistor in order to adjust the trace delay and reduce the possibility of reflections getting out of hand.

Comment: I think maybe I wasn't very clear in the description. The vias marked in the picture are the receivers of the clock, not the transmitters. o my question actually was, why not put the termination resistor even closer to the receiver?

Comment: @SomethingBetter See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. It just seems weird to me that the resistor is placed far away from the via, which necessitates that they length-match the termination lines, as opposed to placing the resistor right under the vias, and using very, *very* small lines to connect the vias to the resistor.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding terminology, this seems to be an example of a "fly-by" termination.

From http://www.interfacebus.com/Design_Termination.html#f:

> Placing the termination at the far end just at the input pin works well in many situations. For larger chips, such as FPGA's, which can be 1 inch square a technique called Fly-By termination is used. Fly-By termination places the termination past the device which puts the termination at the end of the trace. In this case Fly-By termination increases the trace length by an inch, the resistor is still an inch from the input pin, but at the end of the trace and not an inch before the input pin.